# How to select column values with alias mysql?

Tags: mysql

Consider my table contains the following data
Table name : Test

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | commodity |
+------+-----------+
| 123  | apple     |
| 111  | mango     |
| 122  | pen       |
| 211  | mango     |
| 322  | pen       |
| 411  | mango     |
| 222  | pen       |
| 311  | mango     |
| 422  | pen       |
+------+-----------+
```

For any id i should get value from my table as follows 
eg;) 
1.for id=123

```
+------+----------+
| id   | item     |
+------+----------+
| 123  | fruit    |
+------+----------+
```

2.for id=111

```
+------+----------+
| id   | item     |
+------+----------+
| 111  | fruit    |
+------+----------+
```

3.for id=322

```
+------+-------------+
| id   | item        |
+------+-------------+
| 111  | stationary  |
+------+-------------+
```

I want to fetch the results like the above for the inputted id value.

Is it possible to achieve this using MySQL query?

Kindly help me.

Comment: [where](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL))?

Comment: @MarcB I guess we need extra table here `id, item,_id, type` and `JOIN` after

Comment: do you expect the computer to know that an `apple` is a `fruit`??

Comment: @alex: probably, but that's up to OP to decide.

Comment: Where is used generally to apply filter for the selected value. But here I need to apply alias name for my selected value.. Is it possible to achieve using MySQL terms.. Please correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: Yeah @alex you are right.. It is up the output to decide name for the value we have in our table.

Comment: what is that table name?

Comment: Note that 'stationary' is an adjective, meaning ‘not moving, or not meant to move’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have those *types* in separate table you can join it this way

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85fb7/1

```
SELECT 
  i.id, 
  i.commodity,
  t.item     
FROM test i  
LEFT JOIN my_item_types t # <- here is your table name goes
ON i.id = t.id
```

or, from what I got from your comments, if you don't have this information yet,
you can just add new column to current table this way:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53ff5/1

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN `item_type` VARCHAR(30);

UPDATE test SET item_type ='fruit' WHERE id IN ( 123  ,111  );
UPDATE test SET item_type ='stationary' WHERE id IN ( 322  );
```

**UPDATE** So you want to get that information even without adding a column? that is against of mysql concept and very weird goal. But yes, it is possible:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dbf4/2

```
SELECT 
  i.*,
  IF(i.id IN (111,123),'fruit', IF(i.id = 322,'stationary', null)) item
FROM test i
```

Comment: is that last line right?

Comment: @Drew what are you asking about? aliases?

Comment: @Alex Just a  small clarification please.. consider the case i have only three(apple, mango, pen) in my_item_types. Is it must to maintain this in a separate table? Or Is there any possibility of handling them hard coded in the query itself? Kindly help me..

Comment: I would just like to know whether i could interpret these names to some other in query and output it to the user while querying... Is this possible to achieve using a MySql query? Or am I missing some thing out?

Comment: @Alex If I am not asking more is it possible to obtain the result without addition of new column or creating new table? Could you explain me on this please..

Comment: @user1391703 check update

Comment: Amazing !! It works @Alex. Can you please explain me why it is a weird goal? I couldn't get you please..

Comment: look, when you try to type using calculator - that is weird goal. when you try to use string constant to get them from mysql  - that is weird. so if you have those constants somewhere on your side, for example on php side - why do you send it to mysql as this weird query just to get it back to your app as strings? there is no logic behind, and this brings extra traffic between your application and mysql server. and this query is not very efficient from performance perspective. So to me and I think for most developers your goal is unclear and weird.

Comment: Just googled and came across this control functions in mysql. [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html]. Hope might help others who read this post.